# site_url() returns with additional backslashes

Tags: php, functions, site-url, escaping

I am using site_url() function and it returns the address as `http:\/\/vip.local\/cc` where I can see that WP automatically adds unnecessary backslashes. Is this for some escaping purpose? I tried using strpslashes function but that didn't fix it either. Any help?

Comment: This seems like there may be something wrong with your site (or PHP) configuration – it's definitely not *meant* to add any slashes. You're not passing it through another function first are you?  Have you checked what `bloginfo('wpurl')` gives you?

Comment: @WilliamTurrell bloginfo('wpurl') returns null

Comment: Have you tried using the default theme and/or disabling any plugins you have installed? It is possible that the theme or a plugin is using the `site_url` filter to alter the output